# How do i design this menu in Android?

Tags: android, menu

I've seen this kind of menu in many android apps including the Evernote app i like it, but i have no clue where to start? Any ideas how i can lay it out.

[image]

Comment: have a look at [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) for example. A `RelativeLayout` (maybe a `TableLayout`) would certainly work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably talking about the [DashboardLayout](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java). Use this as layout and fill it with Buttons or other elements you like.